# Margin: Auto not centering images

Tags: css, margin

I want to center a set of images that are lined up side by side. Despite using `margin: auto` the images are still lined up to the left. I read in another thread to add `display: block` but that's not working either. Thoughts?

```html
<div style="margin: auto; display:block;">
  <p>
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/tca_horizontal_blue.gif"
         style="float: left;" alt="" width="200px" height="93px" />
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nea-logo-e1431885075484.png"
         style="float: left;" alt="" width="218px" height="93px" />
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Arts-Committee-color1-e1431885177830.png"
         style="float: left;" alt="" width="155px" height="93px" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [§10.3.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#blockwidth), `margin: 0 auto` centers block-level elements because

> If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', their used values
>   are equal. This horizontally centers the element with respect to the
>   edges of the containing block.

However, this is useless if `width` is `auto`, because then the block will fill its containing block:

> If 'width' is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0' and
>   'width' follows from the resulting equality.

Instead, you could use a tabular display. According to [§17.5.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/tables.html#width-layout),

> if the margins of a table are set to '0' and the width to 'auto', the
>   table will not automatically size to fill its containing block.
>   However, once the calculated value of 'width' for the table is found
>   (using the algorithms given below or, when appropriate, some other UA
>   dependent algorithm) then the other parts of [section 10.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) do apply.
>   Therefore a table *can* be centered using left and right 'auto' margins,
>   for instance.

```css
div {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
div {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

However, this may not be necessary. You say you want to center the images. Therefore, instead of attempting to center the block container, you can center its content, using [§16.2 `text-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/text.html#alignment-prop):

> This property describes how inline-level content of a block container
>   is aligned.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width of the div, as well.

```
<div style="margin:auto;display:block;witdth:500px;">
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qqyjgnhw/1/

Highly recommend reading about the box model of CSS. It makes a lot more sense after you take the hour to know what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `float:left` on `img` elements, and add `display:block` they will get centered...
When an element is floating, it is totally out of the flow.